# My template class method returns bad type?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, operator-overloading, return-type

The template class method **return_self** must return a object of type `Class<string>`
. But, it returns `Class<basic_string<char>>`

Why, please check out my code

```
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
struct Class;

template <typename Type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Class<Type>& ref){
    os << ref.value;
    return os;
}

template <typename Type>
struct Class{
    Type value;
    
    Class(Type val): value{val}{}
    
    // Returns bad Type
    Class<Type> return_self(){
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<<Type>(ostream&, Class<Type>&);
};

int main(){
    Class<string> obj{"How are you"};
    
    cout << obj << endl; // This one works fine
    
    cout << obj.return_self() << endl; // Error occurs here
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong: [string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) *is* `basic_string<char>`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` is defined as an alias for `std::basic_string<char>` so they actually are the same type.  That's not the reason your program is failing to compile.

The problem is that `obj.return_self()` represents a temporary, and [temporaries cannot bind to non-const references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/501250), such as the `ref` argument in your `operator<<` function.

You will observe exactly the same error with this code, which has the same problem (trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference):

```
cout << Class<string>{"How are you"} << endl;
```

The solution is to make `ref` a const reference:

```
template <typename Type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Class<Type> const & ref){
    os << ref.value;
    return os;
}
```

(Don't forget to fix the friend declaration, too.)